# Is there a way to get rid of inabilities in Numenera?

Tags: character-creation, numenera

I was invited to a Numenera game, and thusly have been attempting to figure out the rules and such and to build a nice character. I wanted to be able to build a character with the Magical/Mechanical descriptor AND be kind of the social character being that is a good comfort zone for me when I start a new character. If you don't know, the Magical/Mechanical descriptor gives you the inability to talking to people in a positive way. Is there a way to fix this?

I had thought about maybe using the experience expenditure of like 3xp (the long term gain) for my character figuring out how to socialize with people. Is that possible? Thank you for help a head of time.

Answer (score 11):

If you become trained in a skill, it exactly cancels out any inability in that same skill. This is effectively the long-term gain you call out - though you should note that becomming trained in this way counts as one of the four improvements you can take per tier.